# Generic and efficient way to parse various kinds of integers from ByteStrings in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, bytestring

Here's what I could come up with but I don't think it's very efficient or safe:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B8

convert2Int = read . B8.unpack
```

Is there a better way to do this? I found functions in libraries that do it for the `Int` type, but not for other types like `Int32`, `Int64`, `Word64`, etc.

Comment: Style advice: When composing functions, use spaces around the dot, as in `read . B8.unpack`. It looks quite confusing otherwise.

Comment: @duplode: a point could be made that it's quite confusing that `.` is used as the scope delimiter in the first place, but there's nothing we can do about this. (I would quite prefer `/`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most straightforward way is probably [`decode`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.7.6.1/docs/Data-Binary.html#v:decode) from `Data.Binary`:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import Data.Binary (decode)

convertToIntegral :: (Binary a, Integral a) => BL.ByteString -> a
convertToIntegral = decode
```

There is also a `decodeOrFail` there, which produces an `Either` value if the decoding fails.

P.S.: How do I know that `decode` will work for the types you want? By reading [the list of `Binary` instances](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.7.6.1/docs/Data-Binary.html#t:Binary).

Comment: Thank you! I think you meant `a` instead of `Int64`. I submitted an edit proposal.

Comment: @donatello Indeed. Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way I found is to use the [Attoparsec module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.13.0.1/docs/Data-Attoparsec-ByteString-Char8.html#g:14):

```
import Data.Attoparsec.ByteString.Char8
import qualified Data.ByteString as B

convertToIntegral :: (Integral a) => B.ByteString -> Either String a
convertToIntegral = parseOnly decimal
```

Of course, this only works for strings without signs (unlike "-3" and "+5"). One may use "signed" instead of "decimal" in these cases.